# PHP/MYSQL - Check success/failure in case of INSERT INTO ... WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: php, mysql

I use the below query to add/insert a record only if an existing record with a certain value does not already exist:

php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO accounts_mm (abc, name)
    SELECT '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($abc)."', '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($name)."' FROM DUAL  
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT abc FROM accounts_mm WHERE abc = '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($abc)."'
    )";
```

... it works ... but I always get 'Success' returned also in cases where no records were inserted.

```
if($mysqli->query($query)){
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Success!')); 
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Failure!'));     
}
```

How can I check on success and failure for the above query?

Further attempts:

```
if(mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli->query($query)) > 0){
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Success!')); 
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Failure!'));     
}
```

Comment: I tried if(mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli->query($query)) > 0) ... also like added above ... but now I always get Failure in both cases. What am I missing?

Comment: You can't just throw a function inside another one.  Did you even look at the PHP.net examples?

Comment: I did but obviously I need some help!

Comment: Never mix Object mysqli with Procedural. Abra covered it well in the answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query may succeed (not fail) but not insert because of `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.  Just like a `SELECT abc FROM accounts_mm WHERE abc = 1` will not generate an error but may not return results if there is no `abc = 1`.  So you need to check the `affected_rows`:

Use the object as you had been using it:

```
$mysqli->query($query);

if($mysqli->affected_rows() > 0){
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Success!')); 
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Failure!'));     
}
```

Or I guess you can combine them:

```
if($mysqli->query($query) && ($mysqli->affected_rows() > 0)){
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Success!')); 
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('added' => 'Failure!'));     
}
```

Keep in mind, if `$mysqli->query($query);` returns `false` then the query didn't even execute due to an error, however if it returns `true` then the query executed but there may be no results.

Comment: The response sends me an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data. Response payload  ... what might that be?

Comment: I didn't change your echos so I have no idea.